# Merge 3 arrays into 3d array in PHP

Tags: php

I have 3 **arrays**, all the same number that I need to merge into **one 3d array**.

So something like:

```
array1 = 'aud', 'usd', 'usd' 
array2 = 'item 1', item 2', 'item 3' 
array3 = '100', 300', 500'
```

I need to produce an array like:

```
new_array1 = 'aud', 'item 1', '100' 
new_array2 = 'usd', 'item 2', '300'
```

I have tried the following that prints nothing:

```
$item = array();
for($i=0; $i < sizeof($currencies); $i++) {
    $item[$i] = array('curr' => $currencies[$i], 
                            'name' => $events[$i], 
                            'result' => $actuals[$i]);

}

print_r($item);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be doing something wrong as I'm getting the correct result with this script:

```
$arr1 = [ "aud", "usd", "usd" ];
$arr2 = [ "item 1", "item 2", "item 3" ];
$arr3 = [ 100, 300, 500 ];

$nestedArr = [];

for($i = 0; $i < count($arr1); $i++) {
    $nestedArr[$i] = [ 
        "curr" => $arr1[$i],
        "name" => $arr2[$i],
        "result" => $arr3[$i]
    ];
}

print_r($nestedArr);
```

Outputs:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [curr] => aud
    [name] => item 1
    [result] => 100
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [curr] => usd
    [name] => item 2
    [result] => 300
  )
  [2] => Array (
    [curr] => usd
    [name] => item 3
    [result] => 500
  )
)
```

Note that I used the PHP array short-syntax for declaring an array `[]`, which shouldn't make a difference. It's good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Well your code should produce a 2D array, try removing `$i` in

```
$item[$i] = array('curr' => $currencies[$i],
```

So it looks like this:

```
$item[] = array('curr' => $currencies[$i],
```

Also to add a 3D array, you should etiher statically create it, like this:

```
$item = array(
    'usd' => array(
        item1 => array("100" => 100, "200" => 200, "300" => 300),
        item2 => array("100" => 100, "200" => 200, "300" => 300),
        item3 => array("100" => 100, "200" => 200, "300" => 300),
    ),
    'eur' => array(
        item1 => array("100" => 100, "200" => 200, "300" => 300),
        item2 => array("100" => 100, "200" => 200, "300" => 300),
        item3 => array("100" => 100, "200" => 200, "300" => 300),
    ),
    'gbp' => array(
        item1 => array("100" => 100, "200" => 200, "300" => 300),
        item2 => array("100" => 100, "200" => 200, "300" => 300),
        item3 => array("100" => 100, "200" => 200, "300" => 300),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Why are you nesting loops? This is a terrible idea. The $currencies will iterate 4 times, the $items will iterate 16 times and the $values will iterate 64 times. Why iterate 84 times for something so simple?

Comment: Well, it makes sense if you use caching, and have a little more complicated list of values, notice I provided 2 options to create a 3D-array, one fast, and one for bigger lists...

Comment: Oh god... It gets even worse with bigger lists. Let's say he has 3 arrays which all has 200 values in them each. The first `foreach` would loop 200 times, the second `foreach` would loop 40,000 times and the third `foreach` would loop 8,000,000 resulting in a total of 8,040,200 iterations. That's EIGHT MILLION FOURTY THOUSAND TWO HUNDRED iterations. Imagine if there were 1,000 values in each array.

Comment: Haha, I get it :P And its obviosly wrong to design an application like this, I provided the option since he used for loops to create his list, just like you did in your answer. To show him how to create a 3D array with loops...

Comment: It is terrible to design an application like this. Large enough lists would crash the application, or taking a very long time to load. I highly suggest you delete this answer before someone else decides to snap this up without reading the comments.

Comment: I approved your edit :) I would appreciated if you removed the downvote :)